# NSSortDescriptor and to-many relationships

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have two types of objections: locations and history items.
I'm trying to fetch locations which are attached to any history item, so my fetch predicate for the location is "history.@count > 0", which works fine.

I'd also like to sort the location objects with an NSSortDescriptor by the date of their latest history item, which as far as I can make out would be "history.@max.time", this however throws the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one;
    failed to handle history.@max.time'
```

Halp plox?

Comment: Is `location.history` an array/set? (Seems to be one, but you have a singular form.)

Comment: it's a to-many relationship which would imply it is. the singular form is my bad, but i don't wanna mess with it at the moment to avoid breaking anything.

Comment: Joonas, did you figure this out? I am in the EXACT same situation, and getting this same error. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't, currently the list remains sorted whichever way Core Data wants to represent it since I had more pressing issues to deal with. Would be great to get a solution though.

Comment: I totally forgot about leaving the above comment and have since "somehow" managed to get @"articles.@max.postDate", working.

I ran back into this post looking for the answer to a similar issue.
In a different piece of code I am trying to use: @"@max.unreadArticles" and getting the error: The entity Searches is not key value coding-compliant for the key "@max"

I will post what I can see as "possible" things that might have been the fix, in an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, you must only use [collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html), described in the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), for the key paths of your sort descriptors with [collections](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) (`NSArray`, `NSSet`, `NSDictionary`).

You must not use collection operators for the key paths of your sort descriptors with fetch requests (`NSFetchRequest`).

@kdbdallas correctly uses a collection operator to sort an `NSArray`. He is not using it to specify the sort descriptor of a fetch request.

It'd be sweet though if collection operators worked for specifying the key paths by which to sort fetch requests. Please submit this feature request at http://bugreport.apple.com/. The more it's reported, the more likely they'll support it.

Comment: I filed this issue with Apple: ID: 9758650, Title: Collection Operators should work with Core Data, Product: iPhone SDK, Classification: Enhancement, Originated Date: 12-Jul-2011 12:26 AM, State: Open

Comment: I've submitted rdar://10468062 with the same title and an example with Departments and Employees. The more people who suggest it, the better!

Comment: Can't find bug report 10468062 on open radar. It would really help so I could more easily dupe it.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 13 (and friends) you should be able to create a [derived attribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription?language=objc) called `historyMaxTime` with the derivation expression `max:(history.time)` and then set `fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"historyMaxTime" ascending:NO]]`

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but you could always pull back the data and sort it after the fact.  Have a look at [Sorting and Filtering NSArray Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I have where I do similar

```
NSError *error;

if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
    self.feedsArray = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"articles.@max.postDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    self.feedsArray = [feedsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSInteger overviewAmount = [[feedsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.unreadArticles"] integerValue];

    ....
}
```

Comment: Any idea what might've fixed it though? Can't really see anything in that code that could've been the fix...

Comment: I am not sure exactly... Do you have your Entity sublcassed? Both of mine are (so in the example above the entity I am doing the fetch on and the articles entity are subclassed) I do not have anything special in the subclass for articles, so I do not really remember why I subclassed it, so perhaps this was why... Another thought is in my articles Entity the attribute postDate which I do the @max on I have setup in the modal to be indexed. Perhaps try that. Also make sure your date value has a default value. I use: 1980-01-01 00:00:01