# Sort using relationships to-many

Tags: objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I have two models: a Region and a Photographers. A Region can have many photographers and I want to sort the Region by the number of Photographers in the Region. However, I am having a problem with the sort descriptor. Here is my sorting code below:

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"photographers"
                                                          ascending:YES
                                                         comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                                             return [obj1 count] - [obj2 count];
                                                         }],
                            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                          ascending:YES
                                                           selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
```

I get an error below:

**reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'**

I've looked around and other people only mention sorting the photographers but I want to sort according to photographer count. Is there any way to use a sort descriptor with the number of photographers in a set for a given Region.

Comment: Show me your model plz so that i would be able to see what exactly you are looking for.without model its diffcult to suggest you how to solve it

Comment: Basically it has a Region with a to-many relationship to photographers.

Comment: Is there any way I can sort the regions using the sort descriptors because I need to create a nsfetchedresultscontroller with this request.

Comment: Create a class Say RegionDisplay seperately with all properties of the Region and one additional property as NumberOfPhotograhs then create a NSMutableArray .Now loop through every object in your Region and then inside loop create a new Object of RegionDisplay  class and assign every property of the Region that you iterating to this Class property and assign NumberOfPhotographs to the counted value now you can use this array to Sort by Number of Photographs.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18921569/2128900 you can't do that kind of sorting using NSFetchedResultsController's sort descriptors. You have to store the count as a separate property of Region, or do as Husrat Mehmood suggests.

Comment: Yes Michal Ciuba thank you very much,I come across such situations several times and solved them by using same technique as i suggested.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution. I was hoping that Core Data would flexible enough to do this since it seemed to do so much.

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of the underlying SQLite store, not the Core  Data itself.

Comment: In many cases you can use -setPropertiesToFetch: with a instance of NSExpression for the "property". You will get instances of NSDictionary instead of NSManagedObject as the result, which is in many cases good enough. The advantage is that you do not need to iterate over the result, even better, the count expression is executed in SQL. This is important, if you expect many rows.